# edit on php.ini doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, ini

I have PHP in an Apache2.

When I do a modification in my php.ini, like uncomment a module to active it, it doesn't work.
In my `phpinfo()`, the *Loaded Configuration File* is on *C:\php\php.ini*, which is the right place.

I restart my Apache after every edition on the php.ini.
PHP run well on the Apache.

So why I can't active my module ? (Actually I'm trying to active the PDO driver for MySQL)

Comment: Please define"modification" and "does not work". Uncommenting the line where you load an extension does not make it necessarily available.

Comment: Check your PHP error log, it might be that `php_pdo_mysql.dll` fails to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncomment this line to consider extensions :

```
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

**extension_dir** is the problem - make sure you have that pointing to the directory, where your DLL is.